# Wordpress single post page text cut off

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs

I've got a problem displaying the content of a post on the single post page in Wordpress.
I created my own theme using `underscores.me;`
Using the function `the_content()`, user reading the post preview, clicking "read more" is redirected to the single post page; but there, the post display only the text following the "read more".

Sorry, I can' post images.

I checked every code line. I am sure I deleted something, but can't figure out what.

Comment: And we are supposed to guess at what the problem is right? Show us some code and maybe we can help

Comment: I don't want you to guess as well as I don't wont you to waste your time reading hundreds of lines... and anyway i Couldn't post pages of code. Reather, tell me if there is a file you want to see, instead of criticize. regards.

Answer (score 0):

First you need wipe content of single.php end echo something there.

open single.php add following code there.

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();               


          if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
          $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
          if ( ! empty( $large_image_url[0] ) ) {
            printf( '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( $large_image_url[0] ),
            esc_attr( get_the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
            get_the_post_thumbnail()
        );
    }
}
                     the_content(); 

                     comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Nothing else need to do.

**Alternative way**

Open any of theme from a wordpress and copy single.php and replace it into your current theme folder.

Comment: Thank you Vasim. Unfortunately it didn't work. I am getting really crazy. i will try to do the whole site from scratch  hoping to find the bug. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was located in the content.php file. I had ti rewrite it from sratch.